# Notice: Array to string conversion with update statment

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Im trying to create a system to active or inactive my posts.

First I get my sts from my url and I store in my $status.

Then if $status == 0 I will transform my post to active and if $status == 1 I´ll turn my post to inactive.

I´m trying to do this with PDO but I´m getting this error below:

**I´m having this error:**

Notice: Array to string conversion in $updateStatus = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE ...)

I´m already using {$data} in  brackets  but its not working!

Somebody there can give me a help?

```
 if(isset($_GET['sts']))
    {
        $topicId = $_GET['id'];
        $status = $_GET['sts'];
        if($status == '0')
        {
            $data = array('status' => '1');
            $updateStatus = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE news SET {$data} WHERE id=:id");  
            $updateStatus->bindValue(':id',$topicId );
            $updateStatus->execute();

        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('status' => '0');
            $updateStatus = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE news SET {$data} WHERE id=:id");  
            $updateStatus->bindValue(':id', $topicId);
            $updateStatus->execute();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? try `$data="status=1"` and why are you writing all the the other 3 lines in both the `if` and `else` like the only changing thing is $data, so logically you should be doing this to write the other 3 lines once outside the `if else`

Comment: What gave you the idea that `{$data}` would be interpreted as `status=1` by a call to pdo::prepare()? It's not exactly documented behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because `$data` is an array that you are trying to concatenate with a string. Instead, do something like this:

```
$updateStatus = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE news SET status=:status WHERE id=:id");  
$updateStatus->bindValue(':status', 1);
$updateStatus->bindValue(':id', $topicId);
$updateStatus->execute();
```

Technically since `status` is set via your script and not user-data, it doesn't need to be sanitized with `PDO::prepare()`.  So you can say `SET status=1`, and not worry about binding that value.

Comment: Thanks, I know that way it works, but I thought that with an array converted to string also works! But thanks for your answer and explanation :)

Comment: Honestly, I may be missing something. Its been a while since I used pure PDO. But my memory has me thinking that you need to prepare the actual values with placeholders. However, if you want to clean things up, you should be able to bind an array of values instead of one at a time